# 2 seemingly isomorphic groups

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Take the following two groups:
$G_1$
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
 \cdot & e
 & a & b& c\\\hline
 e & e                                       & a    & b   & c \\\hline
 a &a                                      & e  & c&  b\\\hline
 b & b                                       & c    & e & a \\\hline
 c & c                                       & b & a & e
\end{array}$$
$G_2$
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
 \cdot & e
 & a & b& c\\\hline
 e & e                                       & a    & b   & c \\\hline
 a &a                                      & e  & c&  b\\\hline
 b & b                                       & c    & a& e \\\hline
 c & c                                       & b & e&a
\end{array}$$
In $G_1$ there are 3 normal subgroups, $\{e,a\},\{e,b\},\{e,c\}$
Each one leading to isomorphicly equivalent factor groups.
$$G_1 \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z} \times  \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z} $$
$G_2$ has one normal subgroup $\{e,a\}$ which leads to
$$G_2 \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z} $$
Which seems to imply there is an isomorphism between them, but there clearly isn’t.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: What does $\otimes$ mean?!? That is not standard notation at all.  If you mean "direct product, usually written as $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, then  why do you think $G_2 \cong \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$? Anyway, counting elements of order 2 is enough to see that $G_1 \not\cong G_2$.

Comment: The answer to "Where am I wrong?" is where you apparently go from $G/A\cong B$ to $G\cong A\times B$. Quotient groups and isomorphism are not as simple as quotient numbers and equality.

Comment: Why should $\{e,a\}\unlhd G_2$ imply $G_2\cong C_2\times C_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In$G_2$ we have $c=b^{-1}$ and $c^2=a$ so that $b^{-2}=a=b^2$, and hence $b^4=e$, but $b^2=a\neq e$. Hence $G_2$ has an element of order $4$, so that $G_2\cong C_4$, and hence is not isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2\cong G_1$.