# Confusion about factor groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771049/2-seemingly-isomorphic-groups), I had two non-isomorphic groups, but which had isomorphic subgroups and factor groups. So I had groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ with normal subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that $N_1\cong N_2$ and $G_1/N_1\cong G_2/N_2$, but $G_1\not\cong G_2$.

This is seems to mean that, unlike normal factoring, a group can’t be reconstructed (up to an isomorphism) from its factors.

Is that right? Is there a similar notion that does allow reconstruction?

Comment: You might want to add some more constraints, because a group can always be reconstructed if you know the factor $G/\{e\}$. So you probably want to restrict the number and relationship of the known factors to make the question interesting.

Comment: Having read your prior question, you seem to think there is only one "multiplication" among factors.  This is very false, e.g. see [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) and generally, [extension problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Classifying_split_extensions).

Comment: @EricTowers, I was wrong, thanks for the information.
But the factors are the same (up to an isomorphism), so no product could reconstruct it.

Comment: @razivo : In your prior question, the semidirect product  produced a cyclic group from your two factors (it was the one with only one normal subgroup) and the direct product produced a noncyclic group from your two factors (it was the one with three normal subgroups).  The difference is the multiplication, not the factors.

Comment: @EricTowers, how many unique groups are there with this quotient and subgroup?

Comment: And, by extension, what information will i need to save about the group to make it reconstructable?

Comment: @razivo : For the group in your prior question, it is sufficient to record the [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) of one copy of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ on the other one.  More generally, your comment's question is equivalent to resolving the extension problem (previously linked) for these factors.  There may be no explanation of the use of the second and third group cohomologies for this that would be satisfactory to you.

Comment: Here's a way to see that you might struggle to do this. You have found two different groups with a normal subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and quotient $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So this gives us the two groups of order $2^2=4$. Any group of order $2^n$ has a normal subgroup of order $2^{n-1}$ with quotient $\mathbb{Z}_2$. There are five groups of order $8$, $14$ of order $16$, $51$ of order $32$, then $267$, $2328$, $56092$, and finally $10494213$ groups of order $512$. The number of groups of order $2^{11}$ is unknown.

Comment: @razivo : No.  You have everything you need:  There are more products than the direct product.  There are more products that the direct and semidirect product.  These are particular extensions.  Your questions make it clear you do not have the background to tackle extensions, yet.  Gather more background then come back around to this.

Comment: @EricTowers, you are probably correct.