# Semidirect product of $Z_2$ with itself

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, semidirect-product, quotient-group

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771080/confusion-about-factor-groups), I was told that
$$Z_2 \rtimes_\varphi Z_2= G_2$$
$G_2$
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
 \cdot & e
 & a & b& c\\\hline
 e & e                                       & a    & b   & c \\\hline
 a &a                                      & e  & c&  b\\\hline
 b & b                                       & c    & a& e \\\hline
 c & c                                       & b & e&a
\end{array}$$
By [the Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) I know that $\varphi: Z_2 \to \text{Aut}(Z_2)$
I’ve reasoned that Aut$(Z_2)$ is the trivial group.
Then, there is only one option for $\varphi$ which creates $G_1$
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
 \cdot & e
 & a & b& c\\\hline
 e & e                                       & a    & b   & c \\\hline
 a &a                                      & e  & c&  b\\\hline
 b & b                                       & c    & e & a \\\hline
 c & c                                       & b & a & e
\end{array}$$
Where am I wrong?

Comment: So you know that there is only one ismorphism class of semidirect products between $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_2$. It is the direct product, because $\phi$ is trivial. The problem with $G_2$ came up in one of your earlier questions.

Comment: The fundamental thing here is that $1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1$ *does not split*.

Comment: No semidirect product produces $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ from two copies of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.  This is accomplished by a different extension, linked in the prior set of comments.

Comment: @EricTowers, what comment are you talking about?

Comment: "extension" is linked in the prior set of comments.

Comment: Indeed, $G_2$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $Z_2$, such that the quotient is isomorphic to $Z_2$. This does NOT mean that it is a semidirect product of $Z_2$ by $Z_2$. (This is another way of saying what Daniel Fischer is saying, namely that the extension does not split.)  Note that nobody said this either in the previous question, you just misunderstood some of the comments.